# Debugging pySerial write timeout

Tags: python, pyserial

How do you determine what caused PySerial write to time out? I am having a problem where PySerial begins throwing `Write timeout` exceptions after running for a variable amount of time. It can run fine for a few minutes (at approx. 200 bytes/sec) and then fail.

All handshaking is disabled.

Prior to the write timeout, I have observed that no more data is presented on the TX data pin. A few seconds later the timeouts begin. If I disable writeTimeout, then the code runs continually with no new data sent out on the TX pin.

I see in the pySerial code that it just passes the written data to an `os.write()` call. What would cause this to reliably timeout? What would cause it to *not* timeout, but not present any data on the output pin?

---

Specific information about my application below:

---

I am sending data out over a FTDI adapter to an Arduino board (which emulates some dynamixel servos).  I am monitoring the rx/tx lines with a logic analyzer, so I can see what is actually making it through the FTDI adapter.

I am running on Ubuntu 14.04 in a VM.

The code is from the [Dynamixel Controller node for ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_controllers). I have been making small changes in order to debug the problem.

Write method, with print statements added for debugging:

```
def __write_serial(self, data):
    print "TX"

    if self.ser is None:
        print "not open"

    self.ser.flushInput()
    self.ser.flushOutput()
    try:
        n = self.ser.write(data)
        print n
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

Read method:

```
def __read_response(self, servo_id):
    data = []
    print "RX"

    try:
        data.extend(self.ser.read(4))
        print data
        if not data[0:2] == ['\xff', '\xff']: 
            print "RX ERR1"
            raise Exception('Wrong packet prefix %s' % data[0:2])
        data.extend(self.ser.read(ord(data[3])))
        data = array('B', ''.join(data)).tolist() # [int(b2a_hex(byte), 16) for byte in data]
    except Exception, e:
        print "RX ERR2"
        raise DroppedPacketError('Invalid response received from motor %d. %s' % (servo_id, e))

    # verify checksum
    checksum = 255 - sum(data[2:-1]) % 256
    if not checksum == data[-1]: raise ChecksumError(servo_id, data, checksum)

    return data
```

And the serial port declaration. All handshaking is off.

```
def __init__(self, port, baudrate, readback_echo=False):
    """ Constructor takes serial port and baudrate as arguments. """
    try:
        self.serial_mutex = Lock()
        self.ser = None
        self.ser = serial.Serial(port)
        #self.ser.setTimeout(0.015)
        self.ser.setTimeout(0.05)
        self.ser.baudrate = baudrate
        self.ser.xonxoff = False
        self.ser.rtscts = False
        self.ser.dsrdtr = False
        self.ser.writeTimeout = 1
        self.port_name = port
        self.readback_echo = readback_echo
    except SerialOpenError:
       raise SerialOpenError(port, baudrate)
```

The program begins running as expected. At some point (happens sooner at a higher packet rate), no more data appears on the TX output of the FTDI adapter.  Here is the output from the last good packet and the first bad packet:

```
TX
8
RX
['\xff', '\xff', '\x15', '\x13']
TX
8
RX
[]
RX ERR1
RX ERR2
```

The `self.ser.write(data)` call returns 8 (for the 8-byte packet) both times, but data only appears on the output of the FTDI adapter for the first call.

After about 3 sec of trying to send data (at approx. 200 byte/sec), the `Write timeout` exceptions are thrown.

```
TX
Write timeout
RX
[]
RX ERR1
RX ERR2
```

In summary:

- Code runs fine for many seconds/minutes
- Data ceases to be output on TX pin of FTDI, no exceptions raised
- After a few seconds, code begins raising `Write Timeout` exceptions

How can I debug this problem?

Comment: you are writing to fast(too many packets/ too high of baud rate) ... if the write buffer fills up you will see this error ... try 9600 baud ... or/and let the consumer read each packet before sending the next

Comment: Another option if you can configure the buffer size and still want to maintain the current baudrate you can increase the timeout with `setTimeout()` but as @Joran Beasley said first try to decrease the rate...

Comment: although 200 byte/sec is not alot ... what are you sending data too? Im guessing whatever you are sending data to ... either blocks doing alot of processing or just straight up dies and no longer accepts ... I bet your packets are malformed if you are sending it to a comercial device (maybe they need to end with newline?) or if you are sending it TO your own code... then your reciever code is broken

Comment: I also see mutex references which implies threading ... which can get wonky with serial stuff

Comment: Thanks.  I am flushing both buffers before sending a new packet.  Shouldn't that take care of any buffer issues?

Comment: There is no receiver that has to accept the serial data. It is output on a wire to an arduino, running code I wrote.  Even if the data is malformed and not properly read to or replied to by the arduino, it should still be out of the pySerial write buffer.